# HTML5 push/replaceState and the <base> tag causes security exception

Tags: html, browser-history

I have a test version of a site located at a subdomain of the normal site, like:
http://test.x.com instead of http://x.com.

I use the `<base>` tag to translate all resource requests back to the original domain:

```
<base href="http://x.com/" />
```

This tactic worked great until I implemented HTML5 push/replaceState support.

Now, if I execute this statement in the console:

```
history.pushState({}, "", "");
```

... then I get a `DOMException` object in WebKit-based browsers:

```
code: 18
constructor: DOMExceptionConstructor
line: 2
message: "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"
name: "SECURITY_ERR"
sourceId: 4839191928
__proto__: DOMExceptionPrototype
```

... and this error in FireFox 4:

```
Security error" code: "1000
```

If I remove the `<base>` tag and execute the same statement, the new state is pushed, and there's no exception.

A few questions: 1) is this behavior a security risk, or is it a bug? And 2) is there a workaround to prevent the exception, or a tactic other than using the `<base>` tag that will sidestep the issue completely?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a bug, you are violating the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  `""` is a relative URL which will be resolved to `'http://x.com/'` since you used the `<base>` tag. http://x.com is a different domain from where the page is hosted which is why doing this runs afoul of the same origin policy.

Using an absolute URL that points to a resource on http://test.x.com/ in your `history.pushState()` call should fix this:

```
history.pushState({}, "", "http://test.x.com/");
```