# History.js and Same Origin Policy traversing to SSL

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile, same-origin-policy, browser-history

I'm using [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) and trying to push a state change from a HTTP site like:

> `http://www.example.com/some/resource`

... to my secure site (payment page), like:

> `https://www.example.com/payment/for/some/resource`

... but I'm getting this error in Safari:

> SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user agent.

... when trying to push the state change like:

```
History.pushState(null, null, new_state_url);
// new_state_url = https://www.example.com/payment/for/some/resource
```

Doing some digging around, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351447/html5-push-replacestate-and-the-base-tag-causes-security-exception), which suggests that I'm running afoul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), since I'm trying to push a state change across protocols. The suggested answer there (if I understood correctly) was to explicitly push the full URL, but I'm already doing that and getting the same error.

In context, I'm building a mobile version of my site and would like the payment page to load using the same AJAX that I've built around all my other page-loads (I've built my page loader with jQuery's `$.ajax` and some custom animation, roughly similar to what you might find in [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)).

Is it possible for me to push this state change across SSL? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is unrelated to the question, but I've gotten the same error in Safari when calling `window.history.replaceState` too often. I added rate limiting where I call that function and the security error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Same origin encompasses not just protocols and domains, but the tuple protocol, domain and port.

In your case, it sounds like you're running afoul of both protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS) and port (80 and 443).

There are a few standard ways to work around SOP. One way is to set the document.domain on both domains to the same arbitrary string:

```
document.domain = "foo.com";
```

Another good way is to load JSONP across domains using a `GET`.

All this said, it doesn't sound like `pushState` is what you're looking to do. The History API allows you to navigate *on the same domain* without having to reload resources while still preserving. Since this is a completely separate domain, I would just set the `document.location` property to the new URL (your secure signin page), which will reload the page but still preserve your navigational history.